# Fill Transition on a circle based on time

Tags: d3.js

This is a link which shows filling up a circle with 2 colors.
    http://jsfiddle.net/9ChXk/

This is the code:

```
var r = 100;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var grad = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
           .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "0%").attr("y1", "100%").attr("y2", "0%");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "lightblue");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "white");

svg.append("circle")
.attr("cx", r)
.attr("cy", r)
.attr("r", r)
.attr("stroke", "blue")
.attr("fill", "url(#grad)");
```

I want the circle to keep changing its fill based on time...something like this link->
    http://invision-web.net/ticket-status/

how can it be done in d3.js? Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the 'y1' attribute of grad does the trick. You can even add transitions for a smooth effect:

```
grad.transition().duration(1000).attr("y1","20%")
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/9ChXk/18/

EDIT: To have a chain of transitions:

```
var data = ["10%","40%","80%","20%","60%","90%","40%","50%","80%","20%"];
var data2 = [10,40,80,20,60,90,40,50,80,20]
var position = 0;    
window.setInterval(function() {
    grad.transition().duration(1000).attr("y1",((100-data2[position])*2).toString()+'%');
    position = (position+1)%data2.length;
},1000)
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/9ChXk/20/

Comment: var data=["10%","40%","80%","20%","60%","90%","40%","50%","80%","20%"]; If this is the dataset and I want the fill transition to keep changing after a certain delay, then how can it be done?

Comment: you can use have a look at [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

Comment: Can u explain by giving an example of the same. I am new to D3!